# How to add subtitles and an additional audio track to a DVD without having to re-encode the original audio/video data?

Tags: audio, video, dvd, encoding

So I have this DVD with medium-quality video recordings. I'd like to augment it by subtitles (in two languages) and add a second audio track (a translation).

So far I only found tools that require to "rip" the original DVD (which involves re-encoding A/V data), performing some manipulations and convert it back to DVD.

Is there a way to do what I want without having this re-encoding step? The videos are very valuable and I'm afraid I'm not going to do 'em any good by running superfluous encoding steps. I can provide more info about the current format if needed.

P.S. A Linux tool is a plus, but I'll take anything if there's no other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done. Content on DVD is stored in VOB (video object) files, which mix together all the components: video, audio, and subtitles. A "ripper" is only required if the original DVD is encrypted. If it's not encrypted, the VOB files can be accessed directly.

Once you have access to the VOBs, you extract the mixed (multiplexed) content into separate files. Then you add your additional audio tracks and subtitles, and use a DVD authoring program to create a brand new DVD. You would need to use a high-end professional or low-end hacking program that accepts pre-encoded assets; "easy to use" consumer-level programs either won't take the existing files, or will want to re-encode them, as you have found. Depending on the authoring program, it may be easy to add new subtitles, but laborious to convert old ones. Because you are authoring a new DVD, you may lose the existing menus and other esoteric features (e.g. multiple angles) -- if you want them, you'd have to find something that will import them, or recreate them from scratch.

Unfortunately, we're several years past the peak of DVD authoring: some programs have been discontinued and no longer available. Poking around, I did stumble upon [Avidemux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avidemux) which is maintained and looks like it might handle the [extraction](http://en.flossmanuals.net/avidemux/ch018_extract-dvd-files/) half of the problem.

Finally, you might just use your existing tools and re-encode anyway. Given the way DVD video compression works, doing it again may not make it noticeably worse, especially if you choose a high bit-rate.

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation! I think I got what I wanted by extracting MPEG2 streams with Avidemux and stitching everything back together using DVDStyler.

Answer (score 0):

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HowToBurnSubtitlesIntoVideo

Please refer to above article to get you started.  **ffmpeg** is an actively maintained linux tool.  Unfortunately, it is command lined based with no GUI.  You might be able use kdenlive,piviti,openshot or others as many use ffmpeg in the background.

Comment: Thanks! I'm familiar with ffmpeg and I'm cool with CLI. This link shows how to add subtitles to a video file. But I'm looking for a way to do this with VOB files from a DVD without having an additional encoding step (e.g. DVD to mkv or so).

Answer (score -1):

DVDs, and optical media in general are usually not alterable once they have been written.  While there are re-writable disks, they operate exactly as the name implies, you re-write.  The best analogy I can provide would be adding something to the middle of a cassette tape.  You'd have to move the stuff that is already there somewhere else, change it, and write it back over the old stuff.
Even re-writable disks cannot always be changed, it depends on how the data was written in the first place.
Additionally, you would not be able to alter the information on the disk without reading that information first.  That is essentially what the ripping process is.
I don't believe you'll find a tool to do what you're looking for because I don't believe it is possible.
If you look up how optical media in general works (Wikipedia is a good place to start) you'll get a good description of what I am talking about.

Comment: The question was not about whether it's possible to add data on an optical disk. Please re-read carefully.